# How to pass data from an API call to the ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I built an `APIManager` class that has function to make API calls to my API that is working fine. Then I use a class `APIClient` to store every calls that I need to do on my API with the specific parameters such as url queries or POST data.

The problem is that these function are void functions and return nothing. I'm wondering how I can modify this to return data that I can store in a variable in my `ViewController`.

Here is the function that I use in `APIManager`:

```
func makeRequest(toURL url: URL,
                     withHttpMethod httpMethod: HttpMethod,
                     completion: @escaping (_ result: Results) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            let targetURL = self?.addURLQueryParameters(toURL: url)
            let httpBody = self?.getHttpBody()
            
            guard let request = self?.prepareRequest(withURL: targetURL, httpBody: httpBody, httpMethod: httpMethod) else
            {
                completion(Results(withError: CustomError.failedToCreateRequest))
                return
            }
            
            let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                completion(Results(withData: data,
                                   response: Response(fromURLResponse: response),
                                   error: error))
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Then in my ViewController I define my `APIClient` and calls one function on button tap :

```
let apiClient = APIClient()
@IBAction func testTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        apiClient.getData()
    }
```

and then my `APIClient` handles the call :

```
func getData() {
        var decodedResponse: Any?
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://XX.API.XX/XX//XXX/XXX/XXX") else { return }
        apiManager.makeRequest(toURL: url, withHttpMethod: .get) { (results) in
            guard let response = results.response else { return }
            if response.httpStatusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = results.data else { return }
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(Data.self, from: data) else { return }
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anybody has a clue on which way I can modify these files so I can return `decodedData`from `APIClient` and store it in my `ViewController` ?

Comment: Improvements: you should not create a URLSession object for every request. This is very, very .. suboptimal ;)  Move that to the APIManager class - and ensure it will be created only once. Also, dispatch to the global queue seems not necessary. If, then when the APIManager needs to synchronise things, and then it should be a dedicated dispatch queue created by the APIManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the result in your view controller, one of the ways to achieve this is passing it back through a callback, just like you're passing the result from your manager to the APIClient.

```
func getData(completion handler: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void) {
        var decodedResponse: Any?
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://XX.API.XX/XX//XXX/XXX/XXX") else { return }
        apiManager.makeRequest(toURL: url, withHttpMethod: .get) { (results) in
            guard let response = results.response else { return }
            if response.httpStatusCode == 200 {
                guard let data = results.data else { return }
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(Data.self, from: data) else { 
                   handler(NSError(code: 1, ...)) /// <===
                   return
                }
               handler(decodedData)  /// <===
            } else {
               handler(results.error) /// <===
            } 
        }
    }
```

```
@IBAction func testTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    apiClient.getData { data, error in
        if let data = data {
             //do anything with the data
        } else if let error = error {
             //show the error message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's not a good idea to post "code only" answers. It is much more helpful to include an explanation of what your code is doing.

Comment: I will give a try at this, thank you. If you can explain a little bit what you did it will be helpful indeed as I don't fully understanding every steps that you added and why it is a good way to fix my problem. Thank you